# lualatex and mylatexformat

Tags: luatex

I am trying to make precompiled preambles format with lualatex and mylatexformat package. I'd like to have it in a Fmt/ subdirectory of the working directory. Trying this command line

```
luatex -initialize --output-directory=Fmt  --job-name=mainfile-luaLaTeX &lualatex    mylatexformat.ltx mainfile.tex
```

indeed produces a mainfile-luaLaTeX.fmt — but in mainfile's directory, not in its Fmt/ subdirectory.

However, the similar command lines for xelatex or pdflatex work perfectly. Does anyone know the reason for this, or did I not understand something about lualatex ?  Or maybe there is some kind of incompatibility between lualatex and mylatexformat ? Any help solving this problem will be really appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bug in MiKTeX's implementation of luatex. `--output-directory` works fine with TeX Live's implementation.

Comment: So there's nothing to do except hoping the bug will eventually  be solved, I guess.